# Can I redirect one branch of a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I know that GitHub has [automatic redirects](https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here) if you move/rename an entire repo. But I have the following scenario:

- Project whizbang has several branches.
- *One* of the branches needs to be moved into its own repository, so that whizbang/8.x branch becomes a new repository named whizbang8.
- Old links pointing to project whizbang/8.x branch need to be
  redirected to the new repository.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Old links pointing to project whizbang/8.x branch need to be redirected to the new repository.

Not that I know of: a GitHub URL for a branch later exported in its own repo would still point to the old repo (branch), and not to the new repo.